# How to setup .NET 6 with Dapper Identity and Discord Login

Tags: c#, discord, identity, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a login via Discord Oauth2 while using Dapper as my ORM.

[Microsoft has a guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that I have followed to setup all of my stores. I infact can call `CreateAsync()` method and a user gets created in my database, so I believe that side of things is completely setup.

My issues lie within external login. Below you will find what I have tried.

Program.cs:

```
//omitted code that binds interfaces and classes - this code works and is fully tested. it is not related to problem at hand.
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/signin";
    options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
})
.AddDiscord(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "some id";
    options.ClientSecret = "some secret";
    options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson("urn:discord:avatar:url", user =>
        string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{0}/{1}.{2}",
            user.GetString("id"),
            user.GetString("avatar"),
            user.GetString("avatar")!.StartsWith("a_") ? "gif" : "png"));
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Here is the Account Controller Code:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISignInService _signInService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public AccountController(ISignInService signInService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _signInService = signInService;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet("~/signin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn() => View("SignIn", await HttpContext.GetExternalProvidersAsync());

    [HttpPost("~/signin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromForm] string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!await HttpContext.IsProviderSupportedAsync(provider))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInService.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, null);
        properties.Items.Add("XsrfKey", "Test");
        
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet("~/signout")]
    [HttpPost("~/signout")]
    public IActionResult SignOutCurrentUser()
    {
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "/"},
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    //[HttpGet("~/Account/LoginCallback")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        var info = await _signInService.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync("Test");
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        var result = await _signInService.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what happens:

1. I click on the Login via discord button.
2. I am taken to Discord Website
3. I login via the discord website
4. I am redirected back to my website
5. info is never retrieved. `var info = await _signInService.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync("Test");` that line is always null.

I've been struggling to figure out what I have overlooked in my setup as I don't have any errors about anything.

[I am using this package](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers).

Comment: ```properties.Items.Add("XsrfKey", "Test");```  You may be making mistake here!! ~ ```properties.Items.Add("Test","XsrfKey") ```

Comment: I tried that and it had same result as before. Pretty sure the order is "Key", "Value".

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? The only thing that isn't working for you is passing custom properties with redirect callback.
Why do you need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly... We need to take a look at the implementation of the internal method [GetExternalLoginInfoAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#GetExternalLoginInfoAsync) inside SignInManager.cs and take note of all the conditions that could possibly lead to null being returned.

I will provide my answer as comments within the code below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the external login information for the current login, as an asynchronous operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expectedXsrf">Flag indication whether a Cross Site Request Forgery token was expected in the current request.</param>
    /// <returns>The task object representing the asynchronous operation containing the <see name="ExternalLoginInfo"/>
    /// for the sign-in attempt.</returns>
    public virtual async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(string expectedXsrf = null)
    {
        var auth = await Context.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        var items = auth?.Properties?.Items;
        if (auth?.Principal == null || items == null || !items.ContainsKey(LoginProviderKey))
        {
            // What cases can lead us here?
            // * The authentication was unsuccessful maybe due to
            //   - Login cancellation
            //   - Project not running on a secured environment (https)
            //   - SignInScheme property of auth options not
            //     equal to IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme
            return null;
        }

        if (expectedXsrf != null)
        {
            // It is important to note that XsrfKey is a constant
            // declared above in this class whose value is "XsrfId".
            if (!items.ContainsKey(XsrfKey))
            {
              // What cases can lead us here?
              // * You passed an argument for expectedXsrf but
              //   the initialized key-value pairs does not contain
              //   any key for XsrfKey ("XsrfId").
              // In your case the below is wrong:
              // properties.Items.Add("XsrfKey", "Test"); <= remove
              // Pass the value as 3rd parameter in
              // "ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties" method call instead
              // _signInService.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, "Test")
                return null;
            }
            var userId = items[XsrfKey] as string;
            if (userId != expectedXsrf)
            {
              // What cases can lead us here?
              // * The argument passed for expectedXsrf does not
              //   match the value of initialized key-value pair
              //   for XsrfKey ("XsrfId").
              // Ensure "Test" should go with "XsrfId" as key
              // by passing the value as 3rd parameter in
              // "ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties" method call instead.
                return null;
            }
        }

        var providerKey = auth.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var provider = items[LoginProviderKey] as string;
        if (providerKey == null || provider == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var providerDisplayName = (await GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == provider)?.DisplayName
                                  ?? provider;
        return new ExternalLoginInfo(auth.Principal, provider, providerKey, providerDisplayName)
        {
            AuthenticationTokens = auth.Properties.GetTokens()
        };
    }
```

So from the code review these are some possible causes for null:

1. The authentication was unsuccessful maybe due to

   - Login cancellation
   - Project not running on a secured environment (https)
   - SignInScheme property of auth options under StartUp.cs or appsettings.json not equal to IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme
2. You passed an argument for expectedXsrf but the `initialized key-value pair` does not contain any key for `XsrfKey ("XsrfId")`.

   - In your case the below is wrong:

     properties.Items.Add("XsrfKey", "Test"); <= remove this line as "XsrfKey" is unknown.

     Instead you pass the value as 3rd parameter in "ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties" method call:

   `_signInService.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, "Test");`